# Изменение цвета чекбокса в listview когда Selectionmode multiple

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Как можно в **xaml** изменить цвет `CheckBox` в `ListView`?
Он постоянно белый, а в моем приложении белый фон, `CheckBox` попросту не видно. Как его изменить на любой другой цвет?
[image: Скрин]

Comment: смотрите в сторону триггеров.

Comment: не могу сейчас что-то конкретно ответить, потому комментарием. Простое гугление по xaml триггерам быстро даст ответ. Какое приложение разрабатывает Windows Phone или WindowsRT?

Comment: Покажите ваш XAML. Смена цвета, по идее, не зависит от того, находится ваш `CheckBox` в `ListView` или где-то ещё.

Comment: эти чекбоксы появляются если я ставлю для listview selectionmode равным multiple. это не чекбоксы внутри listviewitem.

Comment: Windows Phone .

Comment: А ну Windows Phone, увы, триггеры не умеет. Придется всю логику описывать руками.
Вот тут есть пример как это ограничение обойти http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/05/22/Using-Dynamic-XAML-in-Windows-8-Metro.aspx

Comment: @Erick_Voodoo: То есть эти чекбоксы — часть самого `ListViewItem`'a? А можно переписать для них стиль?

Comment: Да конечно. Только вам придется создать свой Checkbox Сейчас покажу ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если попробовать отредактировать `ItemContainerStyle` у `ListView`, то внутри можно увидеть следующее

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMargin}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Border x:Name="OuterContainer" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContentScaleTransform"/>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TiltContainer"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TiltContainer"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckboxPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckboxTiltContainer"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MultiSelectStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="ListMultiSelect" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="NoMultiSelect"/>
                                <VisualTransition From="NoMultiSelect" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="ListMultiSelect"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NoMultiSelect"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ListMultiSelect">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckboxContainerTranslateTransform"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentTranslateX}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorderTranslateTransform"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="GridMultiSelect">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderModeStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="ReorderEnabled" GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2" To="ReorderDisabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReorderEnabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterContainer"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Reorderable">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform">
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.075" Value="1.05"/>
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1.0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform">
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.075" Value="1.05"/>
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1.0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReorderDisabled"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NoReorderHint"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Bottom" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Right" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Top" ToOffset="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Left" ToOffset="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
                        <Border x:Name="CheckboxTiltContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMultiselectCheckBoxMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Border x:Name="CheckboxOuterContainer">
                                <Border.Clip>
                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,25.5,25.5"/>
                                </Border.Clip>
                                <Grid x:Name="CheckboxContainer">
                                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="CheckboxContainerTranslateTransform" X="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentOffsetX}"/>
                                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="NormalRectangle" Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="25.5" Stroke="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeThickness}" Width="25.5"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="CheckGlyph" Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z" Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="17" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="2.5" StrokeLineJoin="Round" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="18.5"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                            <Border x:Name="TiltContainer">
                                <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentBorderTranslateTransform"/>
                                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Foreground="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0" Text="Xg"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="SelectedBorder" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMultiselectBorderThickness}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0">
                            <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="34" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="34">
                                <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                <Path x:Name="SelectedGlyph" Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="14.5" Margin="0,1,1,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Обратите внимание на **CheckboxContainer** там описывается тот самый "чекбокс" и можно поменять цвет на какой вам надо.

Comment: о, этот вариант хорош, тут только xaml, домой приеду проверю)

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. в WindowsPhone и WindowsRT нет триггеров нет. Все поведение контролов необходимо описывать в полу ручном режиме.

Вот пример как это можно сделать. Аналог CheckedListBox.

Сперва опишем шаблон нашего нового ListView.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewCheckBox" x:FieldModifier="public">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource ImgCheckBoxConverter}}" Width="13" Height="13"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:ImgCheckBoxConverter x:Key="ImgCheckBoxConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

И создаем наш контрол:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="163,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Text}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewCheckBox}">
```

После того как мы описали Xaml необходимо создать конвертер устанавливающий картинку в Image в зависимости от значения MyClass.Value

```
public class ImgCheckBoxConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var obj = (bool)value;

            if (obj)
                return new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/checked_checkbox.png"));
            else
                return new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/unchecked_checkbox.png"));

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _value;
    public bool Value {
        get { return _value; }
        set {
            _value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: а нельзя ли как то настроить это только в xaml?

Comment: Нет нельзя. Если бы WP поддерживал триггеры, то да делалось бы все просто без кода. А так вам придется MyClass реализовывать INotifyPropertyChanged. Картинку привязывать к свойству Value. И писать для неё IValueConverter. Тоже самое и для фона. Это, по сути, тонны кода и Xaml разметки.

Comment: Изменил код, на более вам подходящий